# Ler mais de uma aba em arquivo

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, xls

Meu codigo percorre todas as células da minha planilha e devolve todos os valores que preciso, sendo que neste arquivo.xls tem apenas uma aba.

Agora tenho um novo arquivo para percorrer e são 8 abas. Eu sei que preciso inicializar com:

```
workbook_r = open_workbook('arquivo.xls', formatting_info=True)
worksheet_r = workbook_r.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Onde nesta segunda linha estou definindo que seja percorrido a aba na posição 0. COmo faço para que percorra mais de uma aba em todo o arquivo?
Não apresenta erro, ele apenas não lê a aba seguinte. Não encontrei nenhuma referência na documentação da biblioteca xlrd para ler mais de uma aba.

Comment: Já experimentou o `sheet_by_name` ou talvez simplesmente `sheets()`? (que deve te retornar um array de abas) Nota: também não encontrei nenhuma documentação, apenas [essa postagem de blog](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/10/pulling-data-from-excel-using-python-xlrd/) (em inglês). Não tenho experiência alguma com essa biblioteca.

Comment: Oi, sim. O **sheet_by_name** é no caso eu deu preferir por o nome da aba, ao invés da posição. E somente **sheets()** não da certo, porque não existe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dessa maneira funciona certinho pra mim:

```
wb = open_workbook('arquivo.xls', formatting_info=True)
for ws in wb.sheets():
    print ws.name, ws.cell_value(1, 1)
```

Comment: Oi @sergiopereira, eu consegui. Obrigada pela dica.